# when i run with su or from my user "jruby" starts, and when I start from su- it opens ruby, how fix that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I installed the rails with the help of rvm, and now I can only use the ruby with the su- command, and when I enter from under the root without - or my user, the jruby works and then with errors. How fix that? i want job with ruby, why comp open jruby? and jruby not work, why it not work?

any command with ruby or rails return this error, if i write ruby and any option console return this error, if i write rails s or rails and any option console return this error

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: You need at least to provide the command you are executing, so that  the error messages appear.

Comment: well, any command

Comment: So, if you run a `ls`, you get the JRuby error?????

Comment: _any_ command is pretty unprecise, in particular since there are several ways to invoke JRuby.

Comment: any command with ruby or rails, if i write ruby and any option console return this error, if i write rails s or rails ans any option console return this error

Comment: Then please update your question with this information.

Comment: See: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ - add exact commands you executed, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ - add exact output you received.